# MVC 4 - Compiler Error Message: CS1061

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an image gallery upload which works fine with just the Image Description and Upload image. now i am adding a drop down to categories the images into a specific group folder.

My Database table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [WebsitePhotosGallery] (
    [PhotoId]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [Decription]      NVARCHAR (150)   NOT NULL,
    [ImagePath]       NVARCHAR (200)   NOT NULL,
    [ThumbPath]       NVARCHAR (200)   NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn]       DATETIME         NOT NULL,
    [GalleryCategory] NVARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhotoId] ASC)
);
```

Note: I added `[GalleryCategory] NVARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL` now because of the drop down needed.

My Database Model Looks like this:

```
namespace T.Database
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class WebsitePhotosGallery
    {
        public System.Guid PhotoId { get; set; }
        public string Decription { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string ThumbPath { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public string GalleryCategory { get; set; } 
    }
}

I also have this model

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace T.WebsitePhotosGallery
{
    public class Photo
    {
        [Key]
        public int PhotoId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Decription")]
        [Required]
        public String Decription { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Image Path")]
        public String ImagePath { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Thumb Path")]
        public String ThumbPath { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Created On")]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Gallery Category")]
        [Required]
        public String GalleryCategory { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using T.Database;
using T.Models.WebsitePhotosGallery;

namespace T.Controllers
{
    public class GalleryController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /PhotosGallery/
        DatabaseEntity db = new DatabaseEntity();
        public ActionResult Index(string filter = null, int page = 1, int pageSize = 18)
        {
            var records = new PagedList<WebsitePhotosGallery>();
            ViewBag.filter = filter;

            records.Content = db.WebsitePhotosGalleries.Where(x => filter == null || (x.Decription.Contains(filter)))
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Decription)
                    .Skip((page - 1)*pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize)
                    .ToList();

            //Count
            records.TotalRecords = db.WebsitePhotosGalleries.Where(x => filter == null || (x.Decription.Contains(filter))).Count();

            records.CurrentPage = page;
            records.PageSize = pageSize;

            return View(records);

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var photo = new Photo();
            return View(photo);
        }
        public Size NewImageSize(Size imageSize, Size newSize)
        {
            Size finalSize;
            double tempval;
            if (imageSize.Height > newSize.Height || imageSize.Width > newSize.Width)
            {
                if (imageSize.Height > imageSize.Width)
                    tempval = newSize.Height / (imageSize.Height * 1.0);
                else
                    tempval = newSize.Width / (imageSize.Width * 1.0);

                finalSize = new Size((int)(tempval * imageSize.Width), (int)(tempval * imageSize.Height));
            }
            else
                finalSize = imageSize; //image is already small size

            return finalSize;
        }

        private void SaveToFolder(Image img, string fileName, string extension, Size newSize, string pathToSave)
        {
            //Get new resolution
            Size imgSize = NewImageSize(img.Size, newSize);
            using (System.Drawing.Image newImg = new Bitmap(img, imgSize.Width, imgSize.Height))
            {
                newImg.Save(Server.MapPath(pathToSave), img.RawFormat);

            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(WebsitePhotosGallery photo, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(photo);
            if (files.Count() == 0 || files.FirstOrDefault() == null)
            {
                ViewBag.error = "Please choose a file";
                return View(photo);
            }

            var model = new WebsitePhotosGallery();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength == 0) continue;

                model.Decription = photo.Decription;
                var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var s = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                if (s != null)
                {
                    var extension = s.ToLower();

                    using (var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.InputStream))
                    {
                        model.ThumbPath = String.Format("/GalleryImages/Thumbs/{0}{1}", fileName, extension);
                        model.ImagePath = String.Format("/GalleryImages/{0}{1}", fileName, extension);

                        //Save thumbnail size image, 240 x 159
                        SaveToFolder(img, fileName, extension, new Size(240, 159), model.ThumbPath);

                        //Save large size image, 1024 x 683
                        SaveToFolder(img, fileName, extension, new Size(1024, 683), model.ImagePath);
                    }
                }

                //Save record to database
                model.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                model.PhotoId= Guid.NewGuid();
                model.GalleryCategory = photo.GalleryCategory;
                db.WebsitePhotosGalleries.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

And finally my View looks like this which is where the error now comes is, I hard coded the drop down list:

```
@using T.Database
@model T.WebsitePhotosGallery.Photo

@{
    var galleryCategories = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Group 1", Value = "Group 1"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Group 2", Value = "Group 2"}
    };
}


<h2>Create</h2>

<h2>Upload Images</h2>
<div class="well">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Gallery", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "photogallery", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Decription, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3", required = ""})
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Decription, new { @class = "form-control required" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Decription)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.GalleryCategory, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3", required = "" })
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Product, productCategory, "-- Select Product --", new {@class = "form-control", required = ""})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GalleryCategory)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Choose Image(s)", new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3", required = "" })
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" accept=".jpg, .png, .gif" required />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        <div style="color:red">
                            @ViewBag.error
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

So now immediately when i want to view the Create page i am now getting this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'T.Models.WebsitePhotosGallery.Photo'
>   does not contain a definition for 'GalleryCategory' and no extension
>   method 'GalleryCategory' accepting a first argument of type
>   'T.Models.WebsitePhotosGallery.Photo' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 30:              Line 31:             
>   Line 32:                 @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.GalleryCategory,
>   new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3", required = "" }) Line 33:
>    Line 34:                     @Html.TextBoxFor(m
>   => m.GalleryCategory, new { @class = "form-control required" })
>
> Source File: c:\Users\Huha\Source\Workspaces\Panel\panel\Gallery
>   Panel\Views\Gallery\Create.cshtml    Line: 32

Your help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your POST method has a parameter `WebsitePhotosGallery photo` which is a different model than you use in the view (which is `Photo`, not `WebsitePhotosGallery`) so tha'ts all going to fail anyway. Best guess is you have multiple classes named `Photo` and your referencing the wrong one. And having a `@using T.Database` in your view makes no sense either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you split the solution into multiple projects? If so, try force building the project that contains the class `Photo`. It sounds like the WebApplication only sees an outdated DLL, in which the `Photo.GalleryCategory` property is not yet present.

If build fails (or is skipped) for the `Photo` project, then the last-built version of the DLL will be used.

Comment: Hello Peter,  The solution is one project not multiple projects.

Comment: Along with this conclusion (and with Huha's comments to my answer), if you're publishing to an external server (maybe IIS instance?) make sure you publish the entire project and not just the view. Everything sounds like like your model isn't being reflected as having a new property, thus razor is emitting an error (at compile time of the view).

Comment: Hello Brad, thanks for your respond. Well you where right the 1st time mentioning that my application sees an outdated DLL. Thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 0):

From here, it looks like your view and htmlhelper are a little off. You should be referencing the property via lambda and not via the `Model`. Basically, you're view goes from:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.GalleryCategory, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3", required = "" })
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GalleryCategory, new { @class = "form-control required" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GalleryCategory)
    </div>
</div>
```

To the following (note change to `@Html.LabelFor(...)` call):

```
<div class="form-group">
    @* Reference m. not Model. *@
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GalleryCategory, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3", required = "" })
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GalleryCategory, new { @class = "form-control required" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GalleryCategory)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Brad, thank for looking at my question. I change the code as you have advised but the error is still there. I also tried to completely remove the label and only remain with the drop down but the error still remains when trying to access the drop down.

Comment: Source Error:


Line 32:                
Line 33:                 <div class="col-sm-5">
Line 34:                     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GalleryCategory, new { @class = "form-control required" })
Line 35:                     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GalleryCategory)
Line 36:                 </div>

Source File: c:\Users\Huha\Source\Workspaces\Panel\panel\Gallery Panel\Views\Gallery\Create.cshtml Line: 34

Comment: If i try referencing model.Description or model.ImagePath the code works fine. but when i use model.GalleryCategory then i get the error... When i updated the models i followed the same steps i did when i created the model however i am getting this error

Comment: Updated Error:   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GalleryCategory, galleryCategories, "-- Select Gallery Category --", new { @class = "form-control", required = "" }) ........... i noticed i forgot to change the text box to drop down when sending my question. Kindly assist me, thank you.